# Count items via ForeignKey models, Django 1.11

Tags: html, django, postgresql, django-models, django-templates

I have 3 models:

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    '''...'''

class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shops = models.ManyToManyField('Shop', related_name='shops')
    '''...'''

class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    '''...'''
```

I want to show in my HTML `Brand` and `amount of products` which belong to this brand, smth like this:

```
FooBar    50
BazFoo    25
BarBob    12
```

**How can I do this in the fastest way?** 
I have tried:

```
brands = {}
for prod in products_list:
    brands[prod.brand.brand_name] = brands.get(prod.brand.brand_name, 0) + 1
```

But this iteration sometimes takes ~7 seconds (for the list of 20k+ items). May be there is some kind of ORM trick or something else?
**P.S.** Currently I am getting brands like this, without products amounts:

```
brands = Brand.objects.filter(shops__shop_name__in=[shop])
```

**UPDATE:** Like ***Ivan*** advised in the comments I changed:

```
    brands = Brand.objects.filter(shops__shop_name__in=[shop]).annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products'))
    brands = list(brands)
```

This reduced a time of page rendering, but still that query takes 1.5-3 seconds to go in the page rendering. Are there any options to make it even faster? Or may be any other solutions, like async job or db optimisation-indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Count` with `annotate`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

brands = Brand.objects.filter(shops__shop_name__in=[shop]).annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products')).values('brand_name', 'amount_of_products')
```

Comment: If I use this - I get an error: FieldError at /search/
Cannot resolve keyword 'product' into field. Choices are: brand_id, brand_name, categories, products, promo, shops

Comment: If I use this method - the runtime inreases to 15+ seconds :/

Comment: Hmm, looks like I have found a trick - `brands = list(brands)` in the end reduced the page render time to 5-6 sec. Better than it was on the begginning, but still to slow. Is it real to make it work even faster?

Comment: `values()` should make it faster. I updated the answer. Make sure to access `brand_name` and `amount_of_products` in you html template.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `ORM`

```
from django.db.models import Count
Product.objects.values('brand__brand_name').annotate(count=Count('brand__brand_name'))
```